# Why does update manager not work when PPA is unavailbale?

Tags: updates, update-manager, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I have several PPAs in my package list.

Apparently, some of these are not accessible anymore after the last system upgrade.

Now when I update the update manager it tells me that it cannot update the remaining packages due to unavailability of the repositories.

Why is that happening and the application does not have a possibility to bypass the inaccessible packages?
What can be done to re-enable the update manager's functionality?

Comment: Could you please add the exact error message you receive from update manager to your post?

Answer (score 0):

You need edit you software sources and remove the PPA's which aren't used any more.  Assuming you are using a recent version of Ubuntu with Unity.

1. Open dash (with the windows/super key)
2. Search for application called "Software Sources" and launch it.
3. Click the "Other tab" and uncheck the PPA that you don't want.

Don't worry, the software that you installed from here will not be removed. However it just won't be updated and might not working in the future if the libs that it depends are changed.

Hope this helps.